# How can I match a regex on a substring of the pattern?

Tags: regex

I'm looking for an efficient way to get a regex to greedily match any strings that are a sequential substrings of my pattern. For example, given the pattern "qwerty", I'd like it to match:

- q
- qw
- qwe
- ...
- qwerty

I **don't** want it to match non-sequential texts, or patterns that don't start at the beginning, such as:

- trewq
- ewq
- wet
- wtr
- wert

Comment: Have you tried anything? This is not particularly difficult. Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy! You can use `?` for an optional occurrence.

```
^q(w(e(r(ty?)?)?)?)?
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew there had to be a better way than a bunch of ORs, but for some reason this didn't occur to me.